# Angular Mat-table check all after sorting in current page

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, angular-sortablejs

I am trying to select all (or check all) in current page on the screen. Let say I am in 1st page (as I have implemented pagination), then I want to select all **AFTER** I sort a column.

1. I want to select only those records on the screen (that mean on that page only). For this I already have implemented code and it working **before** sorting.

```js
masterToggle() {
  this.isAllSelected() ? this.selection.clear() : this.selectRows();
}

selectRows() {
  for (let index = 0; index < this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize; index++) {
    this.selection.select(this.dataSource.data[index]);
    this.selectionAmount = this.selection.selected.length;
  }
}
```

2. I want to deselect all (uncheck all) once I click on a header. For this I already implemented code for "name" column and it is working

```js
onHeaderClick() {
  this.selection.clear();
  console.log(this.selection.selected);
}
```

PROBLEM: When I sort "name" column, and after that I sort, it is selecting rows from another page. As shown in picture, I clicked on select all, but to my eye it selected only 2 records, but actually it selected 5 records. The other 2 are from page no 3, and the last one is from some other page.
[stackblitz source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-checkbox-select-all-p574w8?file=app/table-selection-example.ts)

[image: screenshots]

Comment: First off, the array `this.dataSource.data[index]` is the original data, not the sorted data. Therefore, your `index` is incorrectly choosing the wrong items. If you want an array of the sorted data, something like this ought to give it to you. `const sortedDataArray = this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.filteredData,this.dataSource.sort);`

Comment: I think the problem may be is that u are not selecting the items in the same list u are sorting them because if u pay attention those items that were selected are the first 5 items , u can know that in their ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to operate on the `sortedData` list in your `selectRows()` method:

```
selectRows() {
    var sortedData = this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.data, this.sort);
    for (let index = this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex * this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize; index < (this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex + 1)* this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize; index++) {
        this.selection.select(sortedData[index]);
        this.selectionAmount = this.selection.selected.length;
    }
}
```